# Relationship between body fat percentage and heart rate / perspiration during aerobic exercise

Tags: cardio, heart-rate, target-heart-rate

I’m at 25% body fat and weight 87.5 KG. I use the cross trainer for 2-1 splits. My heart rate is 194-196 at resistance 10 recovering down to 186 at resistance 3. I can keep this routine up for 60-90 minutes 5-6 times a week.

I feel I am quite adapted to this routine, I have built it up gradually. I breathe normally throughout and I feel generally fine afterwards — it’s getting better over time. I sweat profusely though and my heart rate concerns me — it has always been high during exercise.

I’d like it to be normal but at a stride of 150 and resistance 2-4 my heart rate will stay in the 170-180 range so lower intensity isn’t the key -- especially since my lungs and muscles are adapting as normal. I’d need to stick to walking to be in the MAF formula 180-35 (+15) range.

Since I sweat like mad I assume my body fat percentage is making it hard for my body to loose heat and I’d need a higher heart rate to cool my body down. Should I  expect to have a more normal exercising heart rate once I get down to the 10-15% body fat range ?

Answer (score 1):

Your cardiovascular fitness and genetics are likely to play a larger role on your heart rate than your body fat%

Normally I would recommend long durations of lower intensity exercise in order to  build cardiovascular exercise (long slow runs, etc) however you say "I feel I am quite adapted to this routine". Can you tell us what your resting heart rate it? Some people naturally have higher resting heart rates than others.

As you continue to exercise and your bodyfat drops I would expect your resting heart rate and heart rate at your current intensity level to also decrease. You weight is not the primary causal factor of your cardiovascular fitness, just a symptom.

Comment: My resting heart is 78 at avarage since I started exercising. It used to be 70 and some days it is 70 usually if I haven't exercised.